# Добавление подсветки синтаксиса для assembler

Tags: предложение, подсветка-синтаксиса

Добрый день, заинтересовался ассемблером заметил что на *StackOverflow* нет подсветки синтаксиса для языка [assembler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembler). Язык пусть и не очень популярный, но его еще используют. Вообще я поначалу боялся задавать данный вопрос, вдруг заминусуют, но я имею полное право хотя-бы спросить.

Comment: Тут в общем-то одна подсветка для всех языков, а подгонять именно чтобы хорошо подсвечивало ассемблер вряд ли кто-то будет.

Comment: Ну да, тут в основном css/html/js/

Comment: Но там вроде если используется codemirror можно как-то авто-определение настроить

Comment: Как раз для css/html/js есть кнопка "фрагмент кода". Для всего остального - кнопка `"пример кода <pre> <code>"` и отступы 4 пробелами, ну и соответственно нужно чтобы хотя бы как-то подсвечивало код на двух десятках (если не больше) разных языков программирования. Сомневаюсь, что тут вообще реально сделать какое-то автоопределение языка.

Comment: Ну хотя если подсветка похапе кривая то о ассемблере стоит только мечтать

Comment: _Stack Exchange does not maintain this highlighter. Visit [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) for language support._

Comment: ну и список поддерживаемых языков: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @insolor а вот и нет, разные подсветки тут. На странице метки можно выбрать подходящий парсер.

Comment: @Duoxx было выбрано `none`, поменял на `default`. Посмотрите, стало ли лучше? (варианта `assembly` нет).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, по поводу привязки подсветки к метке буду знать. По поводу текущей подсветки - по-моему ничего не поменялось)

Comment: @insolor значит, пока ничего нельзя улучшить. Ждем, когда замержат уже готовый ПР https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/486

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Из раздела расширенной справки по форматированию

> Код подсвечивается с помощью [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). В большинстве случаев язык подсветки синтаксиса [будет определяться метками вопроса](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082).
>
> ...
>
> Вы можете использовать [один из поддерживаемых кодов языка для оформления](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109), например `lang-cpp` или `lang-sql`, или указать метку и язык подсветки синтаксиса (связанный с данной меткой), который будет использоваться.

Ассемблера среди того списка, к сожалению, нету. Но из-за того, что для подсветки используется сторонний инструмент, все запросы функциональности следует отправлять туда. Впрочем, кое-кто уже открыл [PR на GitHub](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/486). Правда, не ясно, сколько времени надо будет ждать, пока его примут, но сейчас можно по крайней мере понаставить там плюсиков.